# Why is this $ajax call performing a GET when i specify POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers

Why is this `$ajax` call performing a *GET* when I specify *POST*? "payload" is just some valid json

```
function configureOptions(token, endpoint, postdata, reqtype){
        requestOptions = {
            url: apiUrl+ endpoint,
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            contentType:'application/json',
            access_token: token,
            data: postdata
        }
}

configureOptions(token, '/familynet/postchildren', payload, 'POST')
        $.ajax(requestOptions)
            .done(successFn)
            .fail(errorFn)
            .always(completeFn);
```

Comment: `requestOptions` - is that a global var?

Comment: By the way, you don't transfer the contents of `reqtype` into the requestOptions. However, this is not the source of the problem.

Comment: How do you know for sure that it's doing a GET? Have you checked the browser's network console?

Comment: your code seems correct... in modern browsers also if requestOptions is not defined globally... when you call configureOptions it will created... so... are you really sure that the problem isn't in the service API that you call? can you post some information about the request that you find in your browser console when you do the ajax request (in firebug in the NET tab inside XHR)?

Comment: requestOptions is a global val if i console log them out they are all correct..

Comment: Pointy, yes, I've checked the console, I know it's doing a GET because it says "GET" there when it fails.. also because the route is a post route and it's trying to make a GET to the post url.

Comment: i can give you the full console error here: i am logging out the objects also:

Comment: GET http://theurl.com:8102/familynet/postchildren/ 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.8.1.min.js:2
failure  
Object {readyState: 4, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, getResponseHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
 data.js:135
completeFn  
Object {readyState: 4, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, getResponseHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}

Comment: thanks for the responses btw!! :-)

Comment: if you want to see the code the the full js file it's here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917291/ajax-failing-to-post-ignoring-request-headers-and-type-property-set-to-post

Comment: it works in this fiddle but not in the above file: http://jsfiddle.net/loudowl/GDsGD/4/